# Published custom posts missing

Tags: php, posts, functions, 404-error, server

On my wordpress dashboard I noticed a large number of past posts were missing.

> All (708) | Published (386) | Drafts (17) | Pending (8) | Private (1) | Trash (3) - Total 412

Our items are custom post types in wordpress terminology. There is nothing in our theme which manage these statuses and count items. We use wordpress functions to add and edit items. So I believe this is some wordpress issue.

I've no idea what happened.

1) I checked the logs - nothing found

2) I deactivated all plugins - no change

3) I checked the DB and the past posts are in there?

Really need your suggestions

Comment: Please don't ask for urgent help, it usually never arrives. We are all here in our free time to help others where we can. Instead of asking for urgent help, work on the quality of your question. Good quality clear questions usually get positive feedback

Comment: Thanks Pieter, sorry having a really stressful time with this issue. Thanks for the pointers, i'll think first before posting

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the [Query Monitor plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) This will help you troubleshoot your problem by showing you the db query's, hooks, actions, and filters for the active page.

Comment: thanks for that, I'm new to all this but that really helps